# Is it possible to protect certain data from a swap-out operation?

Tags: memory, swap, mmap

I have an issue.

I want my data is always kept in the main memory.
So when I allocate the memory by malloc or mmap, is it possible to protect this memory to be selected victim of a swap-out operation?

Can you give me some advice on these issues? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the [`mlock(2)` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html).

However, read the man page carefully, including the  NOTES section; there are a number of restrictions and caveats.  In particular, there may be limits on the amount of memory that an unprivileged process may lock.